# Org-mode: How do I fold all levels but the current in a sparse tree?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

After doing C-c / to create a sparse tree, move the cursor to some interesting place and C-c C-c to remove highlights I'd like to be able to collapse all levels but the current one.

Is there some way doing it? I'd like to maintain the cursor positioned in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `org-cycle` with a `C-u` prefix to collapse all trees and
then call `org-reveal`: `C-u <TAB> C-c C-r`.  (The prefix actually
cycles the whole buffer between 3 states, but after creating a sparse
tree, this seems to always go to overview state first.)  Since you'll
be adding a `C-c C-c` at either end to remove the highlights, you
could wrap all of this into a single command that you give a shorter
keybinding.

```
(defun org-sparse-finish ()
  (interactive)
  (org-remove-occur-highlights)
  (org-overview)
  (org-reveal))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ok. Even better: instead of `C-c C-r` if I do `C-c C-k`     (show-branches) I can see the whole level.